# Unable to print a tag with href using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, request, webdriver

As i want to extract <a href tag but not print any result here is the link https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex---twilight-twinkle/149173.html

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd 
import time 
import re

url = 'https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/ultra-flex---twilight-twinkle/149173.html'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('F:/chromedriver',options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(6)
pageSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
installment =soup.find_all('img',{'class':'afterpay-image'})
installmenta =installment.find('a',href=True)

print(installmenta)
```

[image]

Comment: Use `.get_attribute("href")` to get attribute href from the `<a>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first `find_all()` returns list of elements.You need to iterate.However the anchor tag you are searching its **not** the `child` of `image tag` it is in the **same node**.

Two solutions you have

#1 after iterating use `find_next()`

```
installment =soup.find_all('img',{'class':'afterpay-image'})
for item in installment:
    print(item.find_next('a')['href'])
```

#2 use css selector `select()`

```
installment =soup.select(img.afterpay-image+a[href]) 
for item in installment:
    print(item['href'])
```